# Contains &/ Replace HELP NEEDED (C#)

Tags: c#, replace, contains

```
        if (b.Text == "+/-"){
            if (resultField.Text.Contains("-"))
            {
                resultField.Text.Replace("-", "");
            }else{
                resultField.Text = "-" + resultField.Text;
            };
            return;
        };
```

This code won't work, it's meant to toggle the negativity on a calculator.

Comment: Please add more context to the question. Its doesn't describe your problem in a reproducible way

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 resultField.Text = ResultField.Text.IndexOf("-")>-1?ResultField.Text.Replace("-",""):"-"+ResultField.Text;
```

That's a syntactic shortcut for saying if text contains "-" then replace else prepend "-" to text value

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the above for the first if case.

```
resultField.Text = resultField.Text.Replace("-", "");
```